Is factorization over $\bar{k}$ unique?
I was trying to show $x^4+1\in F_3[x]$ is reducible. Let $k$ be a fixed algebraic closure of $F_3$. Now I get the following expressions:
$$x^4 + 1 = (x^2-1)^2 + 2x^2 = (x^2 - 1 - x)(x^2 - 1 + x)$$ because $2 = -1$ in $F_3$.
On the other hand $$x^4 + 1 = (x^2 +1)^2 - 2x^2 = (x^2 + 1 - \sqrt2x)(x^2 + 1 + \sqrt2x)$$
where $\sqrt{2}\in k$ is a root of $x^2 - 2= 0$ in $k$.
Now, I know $F[x]$ is a UFD for $F$ a field, but viewed as a polynomial in $k[x]$, they are not unique. Is there fault in my argument?

Note that none of the two factorizations you found are factorizations into irreducibles over $k$. Over an algebraically closed field, the only irreducible polynomials are of degree $1$.

If $K$ is an algebraically closed field, all polynomials in $K[x]$ split into linear factors. This is the definition of an algebraically closed field.
In your case, his means that we can write $x^4 + 1 = (x - a)(x - b)(x - c)(x - d)$ for some $a, b, c, d \in k$. In particular, we can group these linear factors to obtain
$$
x^2 - 1 - x = (x - a)(x - b) \\
x^2 - 1 + x = (x - c)(x - d) \\
$$
and
$$
x^2 + 1 - \sqrt{2} x = (x - a)(x - c) \\
x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{2} x = (x - b)(x - d) \\
$$

Your first expression is the unique factorisation of $x^4+1 \in F_3[x]$ with irreducible factors.
Your second expression is a factorisation of $x^4+1 \in k$ (the algebraic closure). Note that, viewed in $k[x],$ neither factorisation has irreducible factors. To find the complete factorisation, you can calculate the maximum common divisors using Euclid's algorithm.
